# Error running heroku: Symbol not found: ___memccpy_chk

Tags: ruby, macos, heroku

I installed the heroku toolbelt for OSX but can't use it. Typing `heroku` in the terminal, I get the following error:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: ___memccpy_chk
  Referenced from: /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/json-1.8.2/lib/json/ext/generator.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: ___memccpy_chk
  Referenced from: /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/json-1.8.2/lib/json/ext/generator.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I find very little information on `___memccpy_chk`; `___memcpy_chk` seems to be much more common. I've tried installing a newer version of Ruby, adding it to `$PATH`, playing with *rbenv* and *ruby-build* but I'm pretty confused. I don't have much experience with ruby. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you try updating xcode tools?

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to have a similar issue on my aging mac. The simplest way to resolve it was installing an older version of heroku toolbelt. You could run sth like this in terminal:

1. rm '/usr/local/bin/heroku'
2. brew install heroku-toolbelt

Which is going to install v3.42.10.